# Django Tutorial: Reverse for 'results' with arguments '(1,)' not found error

Tags: python, django

I'm currently following the Django tutorial and got stuck at module 4 since I keep getting the following error message:

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/vote/
Reverse for 'results' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/int:question_id>/results/$']
```

Below my codes so far:

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404

from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Choice, Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question' : question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**reults.html:**

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: You forgot an open bracket `<` in `'int:question_id>'`... in the `urls.py`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have no idea how many times I checked the code to see what was missing!!!